# Two parallel lines with non-integer points identified: Is it a $T_1$ space?

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem with an exercise.
Let $Y$ the follow topological space of $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the euclidian topology.

$$Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\mid y=0 \vee y=1 \} $$

And let $X=Y/\sim $

where

$$(x,0) \sim (x,1) \leftrightarrow x \notin\mathbb{Z}$$

Is $X$ a $T_2$ topological space? If the answer is "no" is it a $T_1$ or $T_0$ space?

I think that it's not a $T_0$ but my professor told me that I'm wrong. $Y$ is the union of the lines $y=0$ and $y=1$. "Glue" those point I obtain just a line with infinite point glued when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now if I considered the points $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $X$ it's impossible to find two open set (understood as $\mathbb{R^2}$'s open neighbourhood) such that $(0,0) \notin B_{(0,1)}$ and $(0,1) \notin B_{(0,0)}$.

Could some help me? Thanks

Comment: You’re right that it’s not Hausdorff. It is $T_0$, but it’s also $T_1$, which is probably why your professor said that you were wrong. Can you find an open nbhd of $\langle 0,0\rangle$, for instance, that does not contain $\langle 0,1\rangle$, and an open nbhd of $\langle 0,1\rangle$ that does not contain $\langle 0,0\rangle$?

Comment: maybe considering the canonical projection $\pi$?. If I consider the nbhd of $(0,0)$ in $Y$ so $\pi$ applied to this nbhd don't include $\pi(0,1)$ and viceversa?

Comment: What if you let $$U=\big((-1,1)\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big((-1,0)\times\{1\}\big)\cup\big((0,1) \times\{1\}\big)$$ and consider $\pi^{-1}[U]$?

Comment: Why are you considering $U$ in $X$?

Comment: why $\pi^{-1}$ and not just $\pi$? However Will we have an nbhd of $\left \langle (0,0) \right \rangle$?

Comment: Sorry: I was doing two things at once and got $X$ and $Y$ confused. $U$ is in $Y$. The point is that $U=\pi^{-1}[\pi[U]]$, which means that $\pi[U]$ is open in $X$.